# Extracting two names from same sentence in nltk python

Tags: python, nltk, extract, sentence

Hi I started playing around with Python these days and it seems easy so I found the corpus in nltk in Python. When I tried out

```
text1.concordance("Moby")
```

it gave me the number of sentences and a display of the sentences containing the word Moby, cool.

So I tried to test out if I could find all the sentences with the names Moby and Ahab but sadly I get errors out of that.

Am I doing something wrong or should I be able to get all the sentences containing those both names? Is there another function from nltk I should use? O.o

It's probably easy but not so much for me to see it atm...hope someone could help, thanks.

PS: If I need to write some code, an example would be great.^^

Edit:
Since someone asked for the error I will write the code I wrote too.

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import *

text1.concordance("Moby","Ahab")
```

gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    text1.concordance('Moby','Ahab')
  File "C:\Programmering\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 314, in concordance
    self._concordance_index.print_concordance(word, width, lines)
  File "C:\Programmering\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 174, in print_concordance
    half_width = (width - len(word) - 2) / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I had guessed that I would get some matches like with just running:

```
text1.concordance("Moby")
```

where I got 84 matches.

Comment: what type of errors? please paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with `concordance`. It only accepts one word and it prints out the results. There's no (reasonable) way to get them as a list, so you can't filter them further. The problem is that `Text`, the object behind `text1`, is only suitable for simple interactive exploration--I've never understood why the nltk book starts with it. So forget about `Text`, skip the rest of the chapter and go straight to chapter 2. Moby Dick is part of the `gutenberg` corpus, so you can iterate over its sentences and get your answer like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
for s in gutenberg.sents('melville-moby_dick.txt'):
    if 'Ahab' in s and 'Moby' in s:
        print " ".join(s)
```

Comment: Seems like it you are right. /me goes straight to chapter 2 xD

Answer (score -1):

You could make a list of all the names you want to find a concordance with such as:

```
name_list = ['Moby', 'Ahab']
```

The code for doing so would be:

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import *
name_list = ['Moby', 'Ahab']
for name in name_list: 
    text1.concordance(name)
```